# Insert and search quickly

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the best data-structure for doing following operation quickly

- Insert
- Find.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: Is this homework? In the real world, the answer is "it depends".

Comment: depends directly on the ration of inserts and finds; it can also depend on the type of inserts and finds (there might be some useful correlation in data inserted or sought for)

Comment: No homework, I am trying to understand best implementation for graph adjancency list.

Comment: Even that is not enough information. How do you actually plan to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good implementation for graph adjancency lists is using dynamically allocated vectors of integers.

Let's suppose you have at most N nodes in your graph. You can store the graph in an array of N dynamically allocated vectors of integers.
It will look like this:

vector[N]

To insert a edge from node x to node y you use:

vector[x].push(y)

This way if the graph is sparse ( doesn't have a lot of edges) you can find all the outgoing edges of a node quickly.

If you want to find if there's an edge between x and y you have to go through vector[x] and search for it. If you want to speed that up you can additionaly use a 2 dimensional boolean array if the number of nodes is small ( less then 1000 is reasonable).

If you have a lot of nodes and want to speed that operation up you can use a hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

If the same data structure needs to do both of the operations then it should be a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to figure out best implementation for GRAPH Adjancy list. any thoughts

Comment: There's this BOOST C++ Library (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_Graph_Library)

Answer (score 1):

according to me hash_map